# Accessing http request objects outside the functions scope in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, python-requests

I've got this code to make a request to an API

```
var request = require('request');


 request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
 console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
 console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
 console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
    });
```

However, I also a route to serve in my node app and the response I get is out of scope in the route. I want to add the values from my request into view using EJS but with EJS i have to define the values to be used by the file in the `.render()` and getting those values just seems to not be possible.

My app.js looks like this

```
const express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
const path = require('path');
const chalk = require('chalk');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; // Port number

// var url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=1253573&APPID=56e2043a628c776ab619d9d393c2b568&units=metric'; // API Request URL

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/')));
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/jquery/dist')));
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


function apiCall(callback) {
  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var result = JSON.parse(body);
      // console.log(result);
      return callback(result, false);
    } else {
      return callback(null, error);;
    }
  });
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=1253573&APPID=56e2043a628c776ab619d9d393c2b568&units=metric'; // API Request URL

  const x = request(url, function (error, response, body){
  const result = JSON.parse(x.body);
  console.log(result);

  });
  res.render('index',{
      //temp: data.list[0].main.temp,
      place : result.city['name'] // || data.city['name'],
      //wind: data.list[0].wind.speed,
      //desc: data.list[0].weather[0].description,
      }
    );
    });

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${chalk.green(port)}`);
});
```

any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Why not just move the `res.render` inside the `request` callback?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: @tymeJV how would that look?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const request = require('request');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const chalk = require('chalk');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000; // Port number

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/')));
app.use('/css', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css')));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js')));
app.use('/js', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/jquery/dist')));
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


function apiCall(url, callback) {
  request(url, function(error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var result = JSON.parse(body);
      // console.log(result);
      return callback(null, result);
    } else {
      return callback(error, null);;
    }
  });
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=1253573&APPID=56e2043a628c776ab619d9d393c2b568&units=metric'; // API Request URL

  apiCall(url, (err, body) => {
 if(err) {
     // handle error
      return;
    }
    res.render('index', {
      //temp: data.list[0].main.temp,
      place: body.city['name'] // || data.city['name'],
      //wind: data.list[0].wind.speed,
      //desc: data.list[0].weather[0].description,
    });
  });

})


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening on port ${chalk.green(port)}`);
});
```

if you are trying to render after the api call is finished.

Comment: I'm getting a callback is not a function error on this. Are callbacks the best thing to use here?

Comment: updated. looks like you reversed the callback arguments. when calling them use error comes first and results after.